# What is the name of systemic tension of muscles?

Tags: pathology, senescence, pathogenesis

I meat a overtrained friend (25 years old) who cannot rest.
He has all muscles and most of the skin very tense.
He is practising  regularly in gym and sleep badly.
He moves like a stick figure and has complained pains systemically.
The tenseness have now been some years.

I have met once before such a person who was about 90-year old body builder (male) who never run and did no stretching.
Ageing is not necessarily linked to this kind of tenseness.
I have not seen such tenseness in women.
So I think it is related to the muscles.

**Possible pathogenesis**. Probable causes of this kind of systemic tension

- fibrinous inflammation starting from upper body

  - etc posterior, medial scapula;
  - middle inferior posterior clavicula
- starting as membranous inflammation
- long-term accumulation of fibrin and proteins in lymphatic system in interstitial spaces

  - proceeding on muscular membranes and through lymphatic system into axillary zone
  - axillary lymph nodes
- deep injury of lymph conduction system as a consequence of decreased lymphatic drainage
- proceeding into pseudomembranous inflammation in the upper body

  - starting from axillary lymphatic system
  - proceeding back to to the origin through fibrinous membranes as pseudomembranous to other parts (clavicula and scapula)
- step by step proceeding into extremities and to lower body

  - eventually achilles tendon and foot Thian point glympadenopathy
  - hardening of foot muscles similarly as through upper body

Schematic drawing about the fibrinous inflammation

[image]

**Possible other causes** without citings to literature

- right heart failure
- systemic hypertension and defect in heart (etc fully patent foramen ovale; got idea from [this discussion](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/16482/86))

I am interested what is name of this kind of systemic tenseness, probably muscular origin.
**What is the pathogenesis of this kind of tenseness?**
Why is it systemic?